# How does the fork system call work?

Tags: process, c, posix, fork

If we look at the example

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(){
  int pi_d ;
  int pid ;
  pi_d = fork();
  if(pi_d == 0){
    printf("Child Process B:\npid :%d\nppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
  }
  if(pi_d > 0){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0){
      printf("\nParent Process:\npid:%d\nppid :%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
      printf("Child Process A:\npid :%d\nppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
  }
}
```

For me, this looks like it would create processes indefinitely because, when we fork a process, a copy of the parent is made. So the program code is cloned.

This means that every new process runs the same code; thus, it calls `pi_d = fork()`, and so on.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: The forked process continues on from the statement after the `fork()` call, not from the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from [POSIX fork definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) (bold emphasis mine):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, fork() shall return 0 to the child process
> and shall return the process ID of the child process to the parent
> process. **Both processes shall continue to execute from the `fork()`
> function**. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned to the parent process, no
> child process shall be created, and `errno` shall be set to indicate the
> error.

OP wrote:

> which means, for every new process, it runs the same code

Upon successful completion of `fork()` and return from it **the parent and the child resume right after `fork()`**: none will execute again the first `fork()`, then later none will execute again the 1st or 2nd `fork()` because there is no loop in this code to allow this to happen.

Assuming no error happens (they aren't checked):

- parent forks

  - If it's the child display `Child Process B`.
  - else, if it's the parent, fork again

    - If it's (again) the parent, display `Parent Process`
    - If it's parent's second child, display `Child Process A`

As there's no order guaranteed between which of child or parent will beat the other in exact execution sequence, the 3 outputs can happen in any order or mingled (but on a given specific OS, one display order should happen more often than others, and `Child Process B` having a head start would probably be displayed first).

Comment: I think a key misunderstanding of the OP is that they seem to think `fork` acts like `exec` (i.e. starts a fresh process) with the current executable, whereas it actually "copies" the current state of the program (stack, memory, file handles) with the only difference being the one stated in this answer: one process gets a "0" returned from the current call, and the other gets a (positive) PID returned.

Comment: One of the better ways of explaining it that I've heard is that it's a function that returns twice: once in the parent, once in the child.  (The same way of thinking can help to understand `setjmp`: the 2nd and later time it returns, it's from a longjmp to that saved context.)